# Arraylist<String[]> how to access?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have an ArrayList< String[] >, but how do you get String[] back to normal values?

This is what I got (of course not finished), and I want it to return an Object[][] with my values. Is it possible?

```
public Object[][] noName(String[] col) {
    ArrayList<String[]> arrlist = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    for (int i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
        arrlist.add(createColumnList(col[i]));
    }

// How to get it into an Object[][]?

    // Something made up..
    return new Object[0][0];
}
```

createColumnList is just a method to create an array from different columns in a XML

Comment: I am making JTables, and it's very easy to organize it with Object[][]

Comment: If so, you can create a two dimension array in the first place without using the ArrayList<String[]>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a one-liner, actually:

```
return arrlist.toArray(new Object[arrlist.size()][]);
```

But it would be even simpler (and more efficient) to start with the array directly:

```
final Object[][] ret = new Object[col.length][];
for (int i = 0; i < col.length; i++) ret[i] = createColumnList(col[i]);
return ret;
```

Comment: Hi! This is great! 
This may be my mistake, but I am creating JTables, and with this way the JTable looks like this:

COL1     COL1
COL2     COL2

When it needs to be:
COL1     COL2
COL1     COL2

Any quick tips?

Answer (score 1):

Try it

```
   final Object[][] obj = new Object[col.length][];
for (int i = 0; i < col.length; i++) obj[i] = createColumnList(col[i]);
return obj;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is an .toArray function for Arraylist. 
alternatifly you can do this.

```
Object[][] objarr = new Object[arrlist.size()][arrlist.get(0).length]
      for(int i=0;i<arrlist.size();i++){
            for(int j=0;j<arrlist.get(i).size(),j++){
            objarr[i][j]=arrlist.get(i)[j];
          }
    }
```

This simply loops over every element in the array and puts them in your new array. Chance Object[][] into String[][] if you want to put it in a String array instead.

I think this should also be possible but am a bit fuzy on the rules of recasting arrays.

```
Object[][] objarr = new Object[arrlist.size()][];
       for(int i=0;i<arrlist.size();i++){
           objarr=arrlist.get(i);
       }
```

Comment: `j<arrlist.get(i).length` instead?

Answer (score 0):

You just to loop and `Object` array to store. Here is the code to add to your comment place:

```
List<String[]> arrList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
Object[][] objArray = new Object[ arrList.size() ][ col.length ];
for ( int i = 0; i < arrList.size(); i++ )
    objArray[ i ] = arrList.get( i );
```

I think that will be what you want.